# How to convert Hex to binary in C and output binary as a char array?

Tags: arrays, c, binary, char, hex

I'm trying to write a function that converts hex char into binary array so it's easy to read all the ones and zeros one by one. Am having problems with the code. I currently have written the code below. It gives me an error saying that it returns an address of a local variable, even though I tried to make it return a `char`.

```
char *hex_to_bin(const char input[]) {
    char output[] = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (input[i]) {
        switch (input[i]) {
          case '0':
            strcat(output, "0000");
            break;
          case '1':
            strcat(output, "0001");
            break;
          case '2':
            strcat(output, "0010");
            break;
          case '3':
            strcat(output, "0011");
            break;
          case '4':
            strcat(output, "0100");
            break;
          case '5':
            strcat(output, "0101");
            break;
          case '6':
            strcat(output, "0110");
            break;
          case '7':
            strcat(output, "0111");
            break;
          case '8':
            strcat(output, "1000");
            break;
          case '9':
            strcat(output, "1001");
            break;
          case 'A':
            strcat(output, "1010");
            break;
          case 'B':
            strcat(output, "1011");
            break;
          case 'C':
            strcat(output, "1100");
            break;
          case 'D':
            strcat(output, "1101");
            break;
          case 'E':
            strcat(output, "1110");
            break;
          case 'F':
            strcat(output, "1111");
            break;
          case 'a':
            strcat(output, "1010");
            break;
          case 'b':
            strcat(output, "1011");
            break;
          case 'c':
            strcat(output, "1100");
            break;
          case 'd':
            strcat(output, "1101");
            break;
          case 'e':
            strcat(output, "1110");
            break;
          case 'f':
            strcat(output, "1111");
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Perhaps this is a silly approach, but I only recently picked up C.

Comment: `char output[] = "";` That array can only hold one char. You need to pick a size. Ex `char output[128] = "";`

Comment: `return output;` is going to blow up too. `output` is a local array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 major problems in your code:

- `char output[] = "";` defines an array of `char` just large enough to hold the empty string. For you purpose, you should allocate an array with a size `4 * strlen(input) + 1`
- `return output;` returns the address of a local object, which will become invalid as soon as the function returns. You could instead allocate memory from the heap with `malloc()` and return the pointer. The caller will be responsible for freeing this object.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *hex_to_bin(const char input[]) {
    char *output = malloc(strlen(input) * 4 + 1);
    if (output != NULL) {
        char *p = output;
        *p = '\0';
        for (size_t i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
            switch (input[i]) {
              case '0':
                strcpy(p, "0000");
                break;
              case '1':
                strcpy(p, "0001");
                break;
              case '2':
                strcpy(p, "0010");
                break;
              case '3':
                strcpy(p, "0011");
                break;
              case '4':
                strcpy(p, "0100");
                break;
              case '5':
                strcpy(p, "0101");
                break;
              case '6':
                strcpy(p, "0110");
                break;
              case '7':
                strcpy(p, "0111");
                break;
              case '8':
                strcpy(p, "1000");
                break;
              case '9':
                strcpy(p, "1001");
                break;
              case 'A':
              case 'a':
                strcpy(p, "1010");
                break;
              case 'B':
              case 'b':
                strcpy(p, "1011");
                break;
              case 'C':
              case 'c':
                strcpy(p, "1100");
                break;
              case 'D':
              case 'd':
                strcpy(p, "1101");
                break;
              case 'E':
              case 'e':
                strcpy(p, "1110");
                break;
              case 'F':
              case 'f':
                strcpy(p, "1111");
                break;
              default:
                p[0] = input[i];
                p[1] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            p += strlen(p);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    char *p = hex_to_bin("n = DeadBeef\n");
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code fails as it attempts to return an undersized local array.  `output[]` is too small and local arrays are invalid once the function ends.

Instead, consider passing in a destination array.

```
// Return NULL on error
char *hex_to_bin(size_t size, char *dest, const char input[]) {
  // Enough room? 
  size_t len = strlen(input);
  if (dest == NULL || len * 4 + 1 < size) {
    return NULL;
  }

  char *s = dest;
  size_t i;
  // Iterate until a non-hex digit found ....
  for (i = 0; isxdigit((unsigned char) input[i]); i++) {
    // Rather than a huge switch table, how about scanning a string of length 1?
    unsigned digit;
    sscanf((char[2]){ input[i], '\0'}, "%x", &digit);
    // Now convert to binary 
    for (unsigned mask = 8; mask; mask >>= 1) {
      *s++ = mark & digit ? '1' : '0';
    }
  }
  *s = '\0';
  if (input[i] != '\0') { // Was a non-hex digit found?
    return NULL; 
  }
  return dest;
}
```